# Perfect forwarding to function pointer call

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile simple templetized wrapper in Visual Studio 2015

```
template<typename Rv, typename ...Args>
Rv call(Rv(*fp)(Args...), Args&&...args) {
    return (*fp)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int iArg;
void(*fn)(int);
call(fn, iArg);`
```

I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
test.cpp(30): error C2672: 'call': no matching overloaded function found
error C2782: 'Rv call(Rv (__cdecl *)(Args...),Args &&...)': template parameter 'Args' is ambiguous
1>         test.cpp(22): note: see declaration of 'call'
1>         test.cpp(30): note: could be 'int'
1>         test.cpp(30): note: or       'int&'
```

Why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You have to split args to allow correct deduction:

```
template <typename Rv, typename... Args, typename... Ts>
Rv call(Rv(*fp)(Args...), Ts&&...args) {
    return (*fp)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: @U.Mann Don't forget to mark the answer as a solution!

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem. This solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be made a bit more generic to call any type of callable thing by having the template parameter be a function type instead of a raw function pointer. [Working example](http://ideone.com/0BJfJR) for GCC. Should work for visual studio.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type call(Func fp, Args&&...args) {
    return fp(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void foo(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int iArg = 2;
    void(*fn)(int) = foo;
    call(fn, iArg);

    return 0;
}
```